# InnoDB to MyISAM Conversion Problem

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, storage-engine, database-engine

I have a dedicated server based on CentOS 5 OS , mysql 5 and phpmyadmin

I was trying to convert all database tables from InnoDB to MYISAM. I tried to do it by setting in /etc/my.cnf file the value

```
skip-innodb
```

Afterwards, I found some errors in some php scripts in the server

```
Unknown table engine 'InnoDB'
```

I checked some databases in phpmyadmin i found in each database some tables **IN USE**

How can I make a successful conversion of all tables from InnoDB to MyISAM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `skip-innodb` does disable the InnoDB Storage Engine, but that does not convert the tables.

You need to script the conversion of all the tables.

## STEP #1

Comment out the `skip-innodb`

```
[mysqld]
#skip-innodb
```

## STEP #2

```
service mysql restart
```

## STEP #3

Execute the Following Script snf View Results

```
CONVERT_SCRIPT=/tmp/InnoDBConversionToMyISAM.sql
SQL="SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' ENGINE=MyISAM;') "
SQL="${SQL} FROM information_schema.tables "
SQL="${SQL} WHERE engine='InnoDB' AND table_schema <> 'mysql'"
mysql -uroot -p -ANe"${SQL}" > ${CONVERT_SCRIPT}
```

## STEP #4

View the script

```
vi /tmp/InnoDBConversionToMyISAM.sql
```

or

```
less /tmp/InnoDBConversionToMyISAM.sql
```

If you like the contents, then ...

## STEP #5

Login to mysql and run

```
mysql> source /tmp/InnoDBConversionToMyISAM.sql
```

## STEP #6

Uncomment out the `skip-innodb`

```
[mysqld]
skip-innodb
```

## STEP #7

```
service mysql restart
```

## STEP #8

There is no STEP 8. That's it !!!

## Give it a Try !!!